# Как получить записи из двух таблиц при сравнении даты

Tags: mysql, дата, select

В двух таблицах содержатся даты добавления записей. В таблицах есть одинаковые ID. Подскажите пожалуйста как выбрать записи с одинаковыми ID только если дата в таблице 1 больше даты в таблице 2.

Таблица 1

```
product_id | date_modified
```

Таблица 2

```
oc_product_id | date_update
```

Comment: обычный join с `a.id=b.id and a.date > b.date`

Comment: ID - уникален в каждой отдельной таблице? Или где-то хранится история, и ID дублируются?